# Не работает Insert - параметрический SQL запрос на Visual C++

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-c++

Конкретнее. К предыдущему вопросу. Следующий запрос дает всегда (у меня) -1 (SQL_ERROR). Если поле типа char, nchar, ... image. Если запрос не параметрический (явное задание значения поля), то все нормально. Версия драйвера другая, не `<?>`, а другой символ для запроса? Что не так?

```
SQLCHAR SQL[]= "INSERT INTO Foto (Image) VALUES(?)";  
sr = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, SQL, SQL_NTS);
```

Бьюсь над решением неделю, прошу помочь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в код вызов `SQLGetDiagRec`, в том случае, когда `SQLExecDirect` возвращает `SQL_ERROR`, и распечатайте его значение в лог. Параметр `MessageText` будет содержать текст ошибки.

Comment: Вызов SQLGetDiagRecв этом случае дает SQL_NO_DATA!